# What is the solution of $f(x)\cdot f(-x) = 1$

Tags: functional-equations

What is the general solution of the equation?

$$f(x) \cdot f(-x) = 1$$

I know that $f(x) = A^{k \cdot x}$ is a solution, and I am *feeling* this is the general solution, but I don't have any proof.

**EDIT:** After I read Didier's answer, I realised I might not have clarified the question. Didier's answer is correct, but I was mainly looking of other than the exponential functions. Vhailor's seem to have given the correct answer, because basically I can get any function, limit it to only x >= 0, then define g(-x) as 1/f(x). So I will mark this question as answered, but if you can think of some examples satisfying the conditions, please share them.

Comment: Do you want your function $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: You say it is a differential equation, so you assume that $f$ is differentiable. Is that right?

Comment: let $f(0)=1$, and let $f$ be an arbitrary positive continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^+$.  then define $f(-x)$ by $1/f(x)$.  (similarly for $f(0)=-1$).

Comment: Hmm... good point about the continuity. Well, I was mainly looking for general solutions, but forgot that differential equations are concerned about continuous functions.

Comment: Your edit is odd. In particular your description of my post is unfaithful (and I wonder where you saw that it was restricted to, or hinted at, the exponential function).

Comment: Take it easy my friend :-) I just didn't understand your solution at the beginning. Thanks for the clarification indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This equation has an awful lot of solutions. To wit, every function $f$ such that $f(x)=s(x)\mathrm e^{g(x)}$ for every $x$, where $s(x)=+1$ or $s(x)=-1$ and where $s$ is an even function and $g$ is an odd function, is a solution. And a moment of thought shows that every solution can be written like that. For some basics about (even functions and) odd functions, see [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions).

**Edit** Since it seems that the *moment of thought* alluded to above should have been described more explicitly, here it goes. Assume that $f$ is a solution. Then $f(x)\ne0$ for every $x$, hence 
$$
f(x)=s(x)\mathrm e^{g(x)},
$$ 
for some real numbers $g(x)$ and $s(x)$, where $s(x)=+1$ or $-1$ is the sign of $f(x)$, and where $g(x)=\log|f(x)|$. Thus, the condition on $f$ reads as $s(x)s(-x)=+1$, which means that $s(x)=s(-x)$, and as $\mathrm e^{g(x)+g(-x)}=1$, which means that $g(x)+g(-x)=0$, or equivalently, that $g$ is an odd function. One sees in particular that, as is the case for every odd function, $g(0)=0$, a fact which was obvious from the condition that $f(0)^2=1$.

A simple example outside of the scope of the formula given by the OP is $f(x)=\mathrm e^{\sin(x)}$.

Comment: OK, your answer here is kind of similar to mine (except the sign, and the addition of the odd function g), but I was mainly interested in knowing whether there is another function (i.e. not the exponential function) which also satisfies the condition.

Comment: The previous version answers exactly that question. You might not realize that EVERY function $f$ such that $f(x)\ne0$ for every $x$ can be written as $f=s\cdot\mathrm e^g$ for some real functions $s$ and $g$ with $s(x)$ in $\{+1,-1\}$ for every $x$.

Comment: Ahhh... I see. Thanks for the clarification indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you impose no additional restrictions on the function (continuity, etc.) then you can extend any injection $f$ defined on the positive reals to $\mathbb{R}$  so that it satisfies this condition, just define

$g(x) = f(x)\quad$ if $x \geq 0$

$g(x) = 1/f(-x)\quad$ if $x<0$.

Edit : If you want your function to be continuous just add the requirements that $f$ be continuous, $f(0)=±1$ and $f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: The conditions that $f(0)=\pm1$ and that $f(x)\ne0$ for every $x$ are not related to $f$ being continuous or not. // Unrelated: I fail to see the relevance of an *injectivity* condition here.

Comment: indeed I was wrong with the injectivity condition (I don't even remember why I put it there), but the conditions on $f(0)$ and non-negativity of $f$ are required for $g$ to be continuous.

Comment: No, these are both implied by the condition that $f(x)f(-x)=1$ for every $x$.

Comment: Right, what i was trying to say was that the condition $g(x)g(-x)=1$ is equivalent to the condition that there exists a continuous $f$ defined on the positive reals satisfying $f(0)=±1$, $f(x)\neq 0$, and such that the relations between $g$ and $f$ given in my answer hold. (indeed, if $f$ doesn't satisfy $f(0)^2=1$ then $g$ defined as in my answer won't be continuous)

Answer (score 1):

According to http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe2104.pdf, the general solution of $f(x)f(-x)=1$ should be $f(x)=\pm e^{\Phi(x,-x)}$, where $\Phi(x,-x)$ is any antisymmetric function of $x$ and $-x$.

Comment: Since the notion of antisymmetric function of two arguments $(x,z)$ restricted to the line $z=-x$ coincides with the notion of odd function of one argument, this seems to be an unnecessarily complicated rehash of (a partial version of) the result already on this page.